# gravityform wordpress need to retrieve the value from the shortcode

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

I need to return a counter for a specific form (id 1) based on the dynamically populated field (id 9) to perform other actions in the frontend and backend

Right now I have a snippet where I hardcoded the value because I can't find any way to access that

```php
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_counter', 'number_custom_population_function' );

function number_custom_population_function() {
    $field_value = 'Evento 05';

    $search_criteria = array(
        'status' => 'active',
        'field_filters' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '9',
                'value' => $field_value
            )
        )
    );

    $conteggio = GFAPI::count_entries( '1' , $search_criteria );

    return $conteggio + 1;
}
```

This 'Evento 05' is the value passed through the shortcode
`[  gravityform id=”1″ title=”false” description=”false” field_values=”event_name=Evento 05″  ]`

But since I have 70 pages using the same form id 1, but with different `event_name` values I need to find a way to retrieve that value.

I tried with `$_POST['input_9'` but it's apparently working only after the form has been sent.
I tried with `rgget`, `rgpost` and multiple other ways with no luck.

Do you have any clue on how to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any need for the values other than upon form submission? Do you already know or can you define all possible `event_name`s?